# Will Mongodb GridFs MyFiles.files get deleted automatically?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have some files uploaded to GridFs which will create Files.files and Files.chunks but now I see that Files.files data got deleted but Files.chunks data still available. I'm not able to access the files without Files.files(ObjectId). Do these files will get deleted after some time or some storage?